# Problem: Associative law and the use of parentheses (Algebra)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

this time I have a problem with parentheses,

[The problem in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3UGg.jpg)

I transcribe it in case you can't see it properly: **How many "(" and ")" symbols do you need to specify completely the order of operations in the product 2*3*4*5*6 ... 99*100?**

This is how I attempted to solve it:

- There are actually only **98 numbers** of a total of 99 to group into parentheses, because ideally, there should only be two multiplyings numbers: 2*3, 56*78 etc.
- Nevertheless, to visualize it better I decided to reduce the numbers to: 2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10.
- I organized them like this: [[(2*3)*(4*5)]*[(6*7)*(8*9)]]*10. After manually counting them, there is a total of **14 parentheses**. So, ***per each 8-number group, we see there are 14 parentheses***. Then, in 98 numbers, how many 8-number groups are there? 98/8 = **12,5 groups**.
- So, 12,5 groups * 14 parentheses --> 12*14 = 168 parentheses in total.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thanks very much for your answers. Still, I don't seem to fathom how it's done. I'll go over it later.

Comment: The image you link to says that parentheses are not needed. What is the real question here?

Comment: That organization is not fully specified. Do I multiply $2\cdot 3$ or $4\cdot 5$ first? Also, $98/8 = 12.5$ and $12\cdot14 = 168$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please do not forget to accept an answer by clicking on the check mark. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write $(\ldots((2\cdot3)\cdot4)\cdots99)\cdot100$ you see directly that you will have one right parenthesis after every one of $3,4,\ldots,99$, i.e. $97$ right parentheses. Together with the same amount of left parentheses you will have a total of $194$ parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Assume you always want to multiply the leftmost pair first. To specify this for $n$ factors you will need $(n-2)\cdot 2$ parentheses.

It is easy to see that this is the greatest number of parentheses you could possibly need and you can also show, moving parentheses around, that each specification requires that many parentheses.

In your case it would be $(99-2)\cdot 2 = 194$.

Another way of seeing this:

You start out with $98$ multiplication operations. Each time you put a pair of parentheses you specify that one of the multiplications happens before the other ones. You need to do that $97$ times to completely specify an order.

Comment: What do you mean by multiplying the lefmost pair first? As in 2 * 3 * [(4*5) * (6*7)*(8*9)...(99*100)]? Also, I don't see the n-2 thing because as far as I know every other number is cloistered, except for 100, the last one.

Comment: I mean something like $((((2\cdot 3)\cdot 4)\cdot 5)\cdot 6)\cdot 7$.
In the example you just posted it is unclear, for example, whether you multiply $(6\cdot 7)$ with $(4\cdot 5)$ first or with $(8\cdot 9)$ so you need more brackets.